# How to add load balancer to aws ecs service with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I want to add a `load balancer` to a `ecs service` module with `ansible`. Therefore, I am using the following code:

```
- name: create ECS service on VPC network
  ecs_service:
    state: present
    name: console-test-service
    cluster: new_cluster
    desired_count: 0
    network_configuration:
      subnets:
      - subnet-abcd1234
      security_groups:
      - sg-aaaa1111
      - my_security_group
```

Now, I want to add a load balancer with the `load_balancers` parameter. However, It is required a list of load balancers. How can I add a list of names of the load balancer that I want to define?

For example:

```
load_balancers: 
   - name_of_my_load_balancer
```

returns the following error:

> raise
>   ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\nbotocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError:
>   Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter
>   loadBalancers[0], value: name_of_my_load_balancer, type: , valid
>   types: \n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs a dictionary which includes the target group ARN, container name and  the container port.

```
- name: create ECS service on VPC network
  ecs_service:
    state: present
    name: console-test-service
    cluster: new_cluster
    desired_count: 0
    load_balancers:
      - targetGroupArn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:453157221:targetgroup/tg/16331647320e8a42
        containerName: laravel
        containerPort: 80
    network_configuration:
      subnets:
      - subnet-abcd1234
      security_groups:
      - sg-aaaa1111
      - my_security_group
```

Comment: Does Ansible create the load balancers automatically as part of the ecs_service task?

Comment: @matthewatabet it doesn't